# Select single property for all items in an array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have the following situation:

- `$catalogitems` defines a collection of `CatalogItem`s.
- Each `CatalogItem` defines, among other things, a NoteProperty called `Policies`, which contains a collection of `Policy` instances.
- Each `Policy` has a property `GroupUserName` of type System.String.

My question is, how do I massage the `CatalogItem`s in such a way that I get each `CatalogItem` with an array of `GroupUserName`s (i.e. without the extra `Policy` object step between them)?

I tried the following:

```
$catalogitems | Select-Object @{Name="GroupUserNames"; Expression = {($_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Policies | Select-Object GroupUserName)}}
```

which does not seem to be the correct way, because it returns results like:

```
@{GroupUserName=BUILTIN\Administrators}
{@{GroupUserName=BUILTIN\Administrators}, @{GroupUserName=MYMACHINE01\Administrator}}
```

The "`@{...}`" notation suggests (it seems to me) that it returns the results in a hashmap rather than an array. Worse, each result element seems to be returned as a key-value pair as well?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure I understood how your objects look like and what exactly you want from them, but maybe something like the following:

```
$catalogitems | ForEach-Object {
  $_ | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty GroupUserNames (@(
    $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Policies |
         Select-Object -ExpandProperty GroupUserName
  ))
}
```

Can be shortened (in the shell, not advisable in a script) to

```
$catalogitems | %{ $_ | Add-Member -p NoteProperty GroupUserNames (@($_|%{$_.Policies}|%{$_.GroupUserName})) }
```

Comment: I didn't realise that -ExpandProperty could also be useful for non-array members (the `-ExpandProperty GroupUserName`), the result seems a bit better :)
However when I tack `| Select-Object Name, GroupUserNames, GroupUserNames.Length` after your expression, I expected the GroupUserNames.Length to contain the number of elements, but it's empty...?

Comment: You cannot select properties of properties via `Select-Object` that way.

Comment: I figured it out, when I add `| Select-Object @{Name="GroupUserCount"; Expression = {@($_.GroupUserNames).Length }}` to your code snippet, it works fine - the GroupUserNames indeed seems to be an array. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I adapted the code a bit to prepare for the case where only a single GroupUserName would exist ... then there wouldn't be an array and the count part would fail.